# Duplicated requests to same url with fetch using vue and webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, promise, fetch, es6-promise

I have weird results displayed in the web console:
fetch() is sending duplicated requests to the same url.

I thought it could be something related to fetch(), but also noticed that on reload of the app (quasar, based on webpack) also the requests to the http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info are duplicated.

By contrast, I noticed that requests handled by jQuery are NOT duplicated and works fine.

I cannot say if it is an error due to webpack configuration, fetch or they way I am using it i Vue components.

E.g. This article points out possible causes https://insights.daffodilsw.com/blog/how-to-avoid-duplicate-api-requests but in my case it is not due to user interaction : requests are triggered at time of relaunching the app (webpack), and particularly the stack trace shows that the requests are fired at time of creating the components, just multiple times.

Example of how I am using `fetch()`:

```
// component - 
    methods : {
       search(input) {
          return new Promise(resolve => {  // a new promise is request multiple times, in spite in created() it is called just once

            var _base = 'myEndpoint/api'
            

            const url = `${_base}fuzzyautocomplete?q=${encodeURI(input)}`

            if (input.length < 3) {
              return resolve([])
            }


            fetch(url)   // so promises are actually different, and duplicated requests are fired by fetch
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {

                console.log(data)
                // resolve(data.query.search)
                resolve(data)
              })
          })
      },
    ....


// and it should be called just once at time of creation

    created() {
        this.search('init first query !!');
    }
```

Could you advise?

[image]

[image: console stack trace]

Comment: not related to the issue but `fetch` returns a `Promise`, so you don't need to wrap it in a `Promise` constructor.

Comment: Called once at time of creation of what? How many things are created?